# Blur specific area in compositor

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, blur

Why this node composition doesn't blur the Material.018? What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong is that for the Image input on the Blur node, you are supposed to plug in the ID Mask, Not your render image.  You will have to add your image in with a Mix Node (set to Add).  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer!